# Get array of ids from e.g xx_numbers

Tags: javascript

How can I retrieve an array of ids with only a prefix in common?

E.g.
I've got a list of say 50 divs and they all got and ID looking like: aa_0000. Where 'a' is a prefix and '0' represents random numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want all elements of which their `id` starts with something common?

Assuming they are all `div` elements, this should work....

```
// Just so we can stay DRY :)
var prefix = 'aa_',
    matchElement = 'div';

// Do we have an awesome browser?
if ('querySelectorAll' in document) {
    var matchedDivs = document.querySelectorAll(matchElement + '[id^="' + prefix + '"]');
} else {
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName(matchElement),
        matchedDivs = [],
        regex = new RegExp('^' + prefix);

    for (var i = 0, allDivsLength = allDivs.length; i < allDivsLength; i++) {
       var element = allDivs[i];
       if (element.id.match(regex)) {
           matchedDivs.push(element);
       }
    }
}

console.log(matchedDivs.length); // Expect 3
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/SZADg/1).

If you want to explicitly match ones with numbers, try the regex `/^aa_\d+$/`.

If you have jQuery floating around, you can use `$('div[id^="aa__"]')`.

Comment: Additionally, you could test whether the browser supports `querySelectorAll` and then use `div[id^='aa_']`.

Comment: @Felix Kling Where is the fun in that? :P (but sure, see upcoming edit).

Comment: @Felix Kling See edit. Is the test for `querySelectorAll()` OK?

Comment: after 20mins of empty objects I figured out that Firefox needs content.document...etc to work correctly.

Thanks alex, querySelectorAll() worked like a charm :)

Comment: @EpicWii No worries, feel free to give me the green tick :)

Comment: First time using stackof ;) got it now :P


People might want to know what I ended up with:
`javascript:var iz=content.document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="bm_"]');for(var i=0;i<iz.length;i++){addbm(iz.item(i).id.substring(3));}`

Answer (score 0):

For people using jQuery:

```
$('div[id^="aa_"]')
```